# Не понимаю почему поток не соединяется с главным после join

Tags: python, многопоточность, pyqt5, gui, pyside6

Почему поток не завершается, ведь `sys.exit(app.exec_())` тоже поток.

```
import sys
import random
import time
import threading
from PySide6.QtWidgets import (QLineEdit, QPushButton, QApplication,
    QVBoxLayout, QDialog)

class Window(QDialog):

    flag = False
    messages = ["Привет"]

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.button = QPushButton("Click me, sempai...")
        self.edit = QLineEdit("Yeah")
        layout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(self.edit)
        layout.addWidget(self.button)
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.send_message)

    def create_thread(self):
        self.t = threading.Thread(target = self.messages_print, args = ())
        self.t.start()

    def send_message(self):
        Window.messages.append(self.edit.text())

    def messages_print(self):
        time.sleep(2)
        if len(Window.messages) == 0:
            print("нет")
        else :
            print(f"{random.choice(Window.messages)}")
            self.messages_print()
 

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication()
    window = Window()
    window.show()
    window.create_thread()
    try:
        sys.exit(app.exec_())
    except(SystemExit):
        window.t.join()
        print(f"Все слова шо были {Window.messages}")
        print("вышел")
        sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Объясните пожалуйста лучше, для чего вам нужен дополнительный поток и какую тяжелую задачу вы в нем собираетесь выполнять?

Answer (score 0):

Я не совсем понял чего вы хотели добиться...

Но, во-первых, у вас поток никогда не завершится, т.к. `messages_print` рекурсивно вызывает сама себя, а список сообщений никогда не опустошается, а только дополняется.

Во-вторых, вы зачем-то запускаете event loop второй раз в обработчике исключений.

Хотя я ни с QT, ни с PySide'ом вообще никогда не работал, но предположу, что вы хотели сделать что-то подобное:

```
...
    def messages_print(self):
        while len(Window.messages):
            time.sleep(2)
            i = random.randint(0, len(Window.messages)-1)
            print(f"{Window.messages[i]}")
            del Window.messages[i]
        print("нет")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication()
    window = Window()
    window.show()
    window.create_thread()
    try:
        sys.exit(app.exec_())
    except(SystemExit):
        window.t.join()
        print("вышел")
        sys.exit(0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Я не совсем понял, что вы хотите сделать,
но вариант работы с дополнительным потоком выглядит примерно так:

```
import random
''' установите ваши импорты
from PySide6.QtWidgets import (QLineEdit, QPushButton, QApplication,
    QVBoxLayout, QDialog, QPlainTextEdit)
from PySide6 import QtCore
'''
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QLineEdit, QPushButton, QApplication,
    QVBoxLayout, QDialog, QPlainTextEdit)
from PyQt5 import QtCore
    

class WorkThread(QtCore.QThread):
    threadSignal = QtCore.pyqtSignal(str)

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.messages = ["Привет",]

    def run(self):
        while(True):
            msgs = self.listMessages()
            self.msleep(2000)
            msg = random.choice(msgs)
            self.threadSignal.emit(msg)
        
    def listMessages(self, msg=''):
        if msg:
            self.messages.append(msg)
        return self.messages    
        

class Window(QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.button = QPushButton("Click me, sempai...")
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.send_message)
        
        self.lineEdit = QLineEdit(placeholderText='Введите сообщение и наэмите Enter')
        self.lineEdit.editingFinished.connect(self.send_message)
        
        self.textEdit  = QPlainTextEdit() 
        
        layout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(self.textEdit)
        layout.addWidget(self.lineEdit)
        layout.addWidget(self.button)
        self.lineEdit.setFocus()

        self.thread = WorkThread()
        self.thread.threadSignal.connect(self.messages_print)
        self.thread.start()           

    def send_message(self):
        text = self.lineEdit.text()
        if text:
            self.thread.listMessages(text)
            self.lineEdit.clear()
        self.lineEdit.setFocus()    

    def messages_print(self, msg):
        self.textEdit.appendPlainText(msg)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: @Тимур что не так ?